# Is the cargo door on this airplane really malfunctioning?

Tags: safety, ground-operations

Recently, I saw that video:

**EDIT:** I removed the Facebook video link which would require sign up for anyone without an account. I've re-uploaded the video here:
https://vid.me/8WYI

In general, this guy's videos seem to me more like a "conspiracy theories" thing, but I hadn't the time to study them and find the underlying faulty logic. So, in that particular video, he claims that the cargo door of an aircraft wasn't working properly and the ground staff simply decided to use a heavy load on the lever in order to open it (or something like that).

Because of that incident the plane shouldn't be allowed to fly (that's what he claims) and also there is immediate safety concern for the people on the ground because of the weight they used.

My questions are:

- Is the cargo door in that airplane really malfunctioning?
- Do the ground staff follow a standard procedure for the "workaround"?
- Although I understand that the way the weight is "hanged" on the that
  lever is not a safe solution, my logic says that it could never fall 
  from that position. Am I right?

Comment: Link does not lead to a video. It leads to an invitation to join facebook in order to learn all about some anti-journalist called Oskar T. Brand.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri You're right. I will try to find another source for the video and update my question ASAP.

Comment: Some people who don't know much about aviation think that the slightest problem on a plane - like a sticky handle - means it shouldn't fly. They would be terrorfied to learn of the amount of items that are legally allowed to not work properly and still carry passengers.

Comment: @Ben -- yeah, they're the folks who need a MMEL dropped on their heads :P

Comment: meh... I was going to include the YouTube link as well, but he doesn't even have this posted on YT. Based on the videos he does have there, with titles like _Marihuana Truth: 420 Trillion Dead_, I'd not put much credibility in anything this guy says. Honestly, if he said I needed to breath air to continue living, I'd question it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears as though the locking handle for the door has some sort of switch in it to allow for full extension of the door only if the locking handle is pulled full forward and, for whatever reason, the door handle won't move into this fully extended detent on its own.  While the workaround is jury rigged at best, it doesn't seem to pose a flight safety issue unless the door can't be locked when fully closed.  It's just another video from an ignoramus in the terminal with a cellphone camera.

Comment: So, even though this might not be an actual problem, it can't be proven by what we see here. And this guy's video could easily mislead other people without knowledge on aviation/engineering, right?

Comment: I like how he writes, "Ready to take off" when they are clearly UNloading the cargo.

Comment: He acknowledges that he's "No aviation expert", yet he's spreading FUD with the best of them. Actually, that's exactly where the FUD comes from - non experts. :(